# Testing mongo replication on OSX

Tags: mongodb

In two different terminals, I start up mongod with:

```
mongod --dbpath 1 --port 27001 --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.1 --replSet test
mongod --dbpath 2 --port 27002 --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.2 --replSet test
```

(data subdirectories 1 and 2 already created).

I go into a third window and run the mongo shell against one of the mongod instances

```
mongo --port 27001
```

In the shell, I setup a configuration as

```
cfg = { _id: "test", members: [ {_id:0, host: "localhost:27001"}, {_id:1, host:"localhost:27002"} ] }
```

then run:

```
use admin
rs.initiate(cfg)
```

The response from the shell is:

```
{
"startupStatus" : 4,
"info" : "hotest",
"errmsg" : "all members and seeds must be reachable to initiate set",
"ok" : 0
}
```

The logfile for instance on port 27001 reports:

```
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] trying to contact macbookpro.local:27001
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] couldn't connect to macbookpro.local:27001: couldn't connect to server macbookpro.local:27001
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
```

It appears that the rs.initiate(cfg) cannot connect to the mongod instance on port 27001. But when I run mongod without --replSet the mongo shell connects just fine.

It isn't clear where I am screwing up but I will bet it is obvious.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  It looks like your host is being detected as the non-resolvable name `macbookpro.local` (check with the output of `hostname` in a bash shell).  You could either add an entry `macbookpro.local 127.0.0.1` to your `/etc/hosts` or change the replset config to use an IP instead.

Comment: 2.2.0 is the version. echo $HOSTNAME returns macbookpro.local. I will try using the loopback ip next. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you `ping macbookpro.local` from a bash shell, is the IP resolvable?  If not, that would be the issue.

Comment: one way you can quickly resolve this (for testing only) is to add --ip_bind 0.0.0.0 to your mongod command.  That will tell mongod to listen on all interfaces.  Of course the way Adam C describes in his answer is an excellent solution as well.

Comment: ping finds macbookpro.local. I see in the log that a service called rsStart keeps failing to connect to macbookpro.local:27001

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it!

It turns out that when one installs MongoDB on OSX with brew a configuration file is created at /usr/local/etc/mongo.conf. In this file there was the line:

# Only accept local connections
   bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

Well, if you look at the log the rsStart error was:

```
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] trying to contact macbookpro.local:27001
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] couldn't connect to macbookpro.local:27001: couldn't connect to server macbookpro.local:27001
Sun Nov 18 18:32:56 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
```

and if I ping macbookpro.local the IP address returned was 192.168.41.1. 192.168.41.1 <> 127.0.0.1 so mongod was refusing to respond. Removing this line from the configuration allowed be to setup replication successfully.

sheesh. I am such an idiot. Looked for hours at this and kept thinking that the machine name when connected to the network was 127.0.0.1. Let this be a lesson to you---don't get old!

Answer (score 3):

Figuring out the hostnames can be painful, so instead of passing the config object and trying to work out what your hostname should be, just do `rs.initiate()` with no arguments on the first host.  That will create the required config, discovering the correct value for you.  It will print out the "valid" version of the config that it created.  Here's a sample:

```
> rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "adamc-mbp.local:27001",
    "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Copy and paste the "me" field and use the new port number, pass to `rs.add()`:

```
sotest:PRIMARY> rs.add("adamc-mbp.local:27002")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Now take a look at your config:

```
sotest:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "sotest",
    "version" : 2,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "adamc-mbp.local:27001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "adamc-mbp.local:27002"
        }
    ]
}
```

You should be good to go :)

Comment: That is a great trick. Thanks! But it didn't solve my problem. I think it is something deeper than that. The log files for both instances report failure to connect to macbookpro.local:27001 for a service name [rsStart].

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Somehow mongo resolves localhost as your machine's name macbookpro.local.

Just add this line to your /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1           macbookpro.local
```